# How to get the integrated result of "KT/C" of a 2nd order system

Tags: numerical-integration, symbolic

this is a noise transfer function of a RLC-2nd-order system.
what I expected result is `k*t/cap`:

1. the symbolic solve inlcludes many `sqrt[]` which should not be exsited I think.
2. the numerical solve is `k*t/cap + 0*I`, why `0I` exist?

Is it possible to get the result `k*t/cap`? both symbolic and numerical solve, how to revise the code, thank you!

Version 12.3

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*res=0.2;cap=0.3;ind=0.2;k=1.38*10^-23;t=300;*)
eq1 = (vin - vout)/(s*ind + res) == vout*s*cap;
Solve[eq1, vout];
tf1 = %[[1, 1, 2]]/vin;
tf1a = tf1 /. s -> {I*2*Pi*f};
tf1b = tf1 /. s -> {-1*I*2*Pi*f}
tf1ab = tf1a*tf1b
Integrate[2*k*t*res*tf1ab, {f, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {(t > 0) && (k > 0) && (res > 0) && (ind > 
      0) && (cap > 0) && {t, k, res, ind, cap} \[Element] Reals}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a way to the result. Don't know if there is a more straightforward one...

Do the antiderivative:

```
I1 = Integrate[2*k*t*res*tf1ab, f]
```

Then calculate the limits:

```
Limit[I1, f -> Infinity] - Limit[I1, f -> -Infinity] // 
PowerExpand // Simplify
```

The result contains two complex square roots in the denominator that may be expanded like

```
Sqrt[x \[PlusMinus] I*y] = 
Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + x)/2] \[PlusMinus] I*Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - x)/2]
```

Use the above decomposition:

```
PowerExpand[
Simplify[-((I*ind*
    k*(1/(Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + x)/2] - 
         I*Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - x)/2]) - 
      1/(Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + x)/2] + 
         I*Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - x)/2]))*t)/
        (cap*Sqrt[2*ind - (cap*res^2)/2])) /. {x -> -2*ind + 
  cap*res^2, y -> Sqrt[cap]*res*Sqrt[4*ind - cap*res^2]}]]
 (* k*t/cap *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing an issue here. Repeating the setup:

```
eq1 = (vin - vout)/(s*ind + res) == vout*s*cap;
soln = SolveValues[eq1, vout];
tf1 = soln[[1]]/vin

(* Out[57]= 1/(1 + cap res s + cap ind s^2) *)

tf1a = tf1 /. s -> I*2*Pi*f;
tf1b = tf1 /. s -> -1*I*2*Pi*f;
tf1ab = tf1a*tf1b

(* Out[60]= 1/((1 - 4 cap f^2 ind \[Pi]^2 - 2 I cap f \[Pi] res) (1 - 
   4 cap f^2 ind \[Pi]^2 + 2 I cap f \[Pi] res)) *)
```

Here is the integral with some unneeded constant multipliers removed.

```
ii = 
 Integrate[res*tf1ab, {f, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {(t > 0) && (k > 0) && (res > 0) && (ind > 
       0) && (cap > 0)}]

(* Out[75]= ConditionalExpression[(1/(Sqrt[2]*cap))*
     (ind*(-Sqrt[cap/((-4*ind + cap*res^2)*(-2*cap*ind + 
                       cap^2*res^2 + 
             res*Sqrt[cap^3*(-4*ind + cap*res^
                                    2)]))] + 
      Sqrt[1/((4*ind - cap*res^2)*
                  (2*ind + res*((-cap)*res + Sqrt[cap*(-4*ind + 
                                 cap*res^2)])))])), 
 cap*res^2 >= 4*ind && 
     Im[Sqrt[2*ind - res*(cap*res + 
                  Sqrt[cap*(-4*ind + cap*res^2)])]] > 0] *)
```

Now we can check this numerically.

```
iival = 
 FullSimplify[ii /. {cap -> 3/10, res -> 2/10, ind -> 2/1000}]

(* Out[83]= 5/3 *)
```

Compare to numerical integration and to exact integral with values first substituted for parameters.

```
In[84]:= NIntegrate[
 res*tf1ab /. {cap -> 3/10, res -> 2/10, 
   ind -> 2/1000}, {f, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* Out[84]= 1.66667 *)

In[85]:= Integrate[
 res*tf1ab /. {cap -> 3/10, res -> 2/10, 
   ind -> 2/1000}, {f, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* Out[85]= 5/3 *)
```